# Validation.HasError tooltip content

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I'm trying to create a custom validation rules mechanism. I want to switch the tooltip style and content when the `Validation.HasError` is true. For this I'm using this:

```xml
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip
                    ToolTip="{Binding  Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                    Tag="{Binding  Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, Converter={StaticResource TooltipJoin}}"
                    Style="{StaticResource WarningTooltip}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The warning Tooltip template is:

```xml
<Border BorderThickness="1"
    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource FeedackBrush}"
    Background="{DynamicResource Color}"
    MinWidth="42" CornerRadius="2"
    Padding="5,3,5,3">

    <!--Holds the image and text for the tooltip-->
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ContentPresenter
          Grid.Column="0"
          Content="{DynamicResource WarningIcon}"
          Width="32"
          Height="32"/>

        <!--Display the text-->
        <TextBox Background="Transparent"
             BorderThickness="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Foreground="{DynamicResource ForgroundColor}"
             Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
             TextAlignment="Center"
             BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The validation method:

```xml
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
  {
     try
     {
        if (value != null)
        {
           var index = (int)value;
           if (index == 2 || index == 5)
           {
              return new ValidationResult(true, null);
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {

        return new ValidationResult(false, e.Message);
     }

     return new ValidationResult(false, "Please select corect item");
  }
```

And in xaml :

```xml
<ComboBox Name="MyCombo"
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            BorderThickness="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsCollection,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Height="30" 
           Margin="50,178,50,42">
        <ComboBox.SelectedIndex>
            <Binding Path="Index" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules >
                    <c:ComboBoxRule ItemIdex="2" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </ComboBox.SelectedIndex>
</ComboBox>
```

I can switch the style between the general style and the warning tool tip style but the content is empty. Any suggestions for the content problem?

Comment: You need to add the code that creates the errors - the xaml seems OK, but you must see that the errors are really created

Comment: @ShayD you mean the validation rules?

Comment: If this is what you are using, yes. Test that validation erros exist.

Comment: The validation mechanism works OK. Only the tooltip content is not ok.

Comment: Not sure about this, but have you tried clearing the content property in the content presenter? At the momment it's set to Content="{DynamicResource WarningIcon}" and could possibly be overriding any value being set.

Comment: I don't improve my answer because I've just noticed that the added thing is actually in the ShayD's answer. Just check out his answer if you can find it working.

Comment: In the ContentPresenter I'm hosting an image. I have a image and after the image a text. If I'm using the ShayD's answer i can't switch the tool tip style but i can display the text. The style will cause an error on the combo box style.

Comment: Is the textbox showing? Is the text change event raised on textbox? Is `Color` resource different to `ForegroundColor` resource?

Comment: The textbox is displayed.  The text change event is not raise. Yes, Color and ForegroundColor are two different resources.

Comment: And if you set the text to be displayed in the textbox to `"Foobar"` instead of the binding is it visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find somehow a workaround solution : 
I put this in trigger

```
 <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
             <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ToolTip  Style="{StaticResource WarningTooltip}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, Converter={StaticResource TooltipJoin}}"/>
            </Trigger>
```

and for the textbox content i'm using something like this :

```
Content="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=2}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is your problem. The `ToolTip` should have `Content` set, not its `ToolTip`. Also you need to specify some `RelativeSource` with BindingMode of `Self` to target the styled element instead of using the implicit DataContext (which comes from your viewmodel):

```
<Setter.Value>
      <ToolTip
           Content="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
           Tag="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, 
                 Converter={StaticResource TooltipJoin},
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
           Style="{StaticResource WarningTooltip}"/>
</Setter.Value>
```

Comment: @lusian_andrei the tooltip is shown but no text? could you try looking in the ***Output*** window to see if there is any notified error there?

Comment: The tooltip is displayed but without the text.

Comment: @lusian_andrei then I'm sure there should be some error notified in ***Output*** window, please see what it is.

Comment: I will check System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Errors' value (type 'ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1') from '' (type 'Model'). BindingExpression:Path=(0)[0].ErrorContent; DataItem='Model' (HashCode=61470144); target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object') InvalidCastException:'System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'BindingValidationSimplified.Model' to type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'.
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)

Comment: @lusian_andrei I've edited my answer, just add some `RelativeSource` for the Bindings, that error will be gone. However I'm not sure if your ***actual*** problem will be solved.

Comment: indeed, the output error disappeared. But the same behaviour. No text on the tooltip. I'm still trying to find a solution.

Comment: @lusian_andrei be sure you use all the code I posted above, nothing should be missing. I stated clearly about 2 problems.

Comment: I used all the code. The binding error are gone, but the tooltip content is still missing.

Comment: @lusian_andrei it's strange enough, that means the `Content` is empty. You can try setting some fixed text for the TextBox to see if it can actually display something.

Comment: If i hard code the text it is displayed.  need to find the proper way to bind this two things together.

Comment: @lusian_andrei I don't think the problem now is Binding, there is not any error notified. I again hope you used exactly my code above, the `Content` here is actually empty. To test it more, you can try setting `Content` of your ToolTip (in the `Setter.Value`) to some string instead of some Binding as currently.